# A bad pun short story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a [feghoot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feghoot) or [shaggy dog story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaggy_dog_story), either by Isaac Asimov or in an collection edited by Asimov, about the poor dependability of inter-dimensional mail.

The story ends with a guy having a "stumpy, sulfur trussed antelope" in front of him, while a "stomped 'sylph' addressed cantaloupe" is on his desk when he is supposed to have received a "stamped self addressed envelope".

Comment: I read this 20 years ago but don't remember it anymore. Would love to see an answer tho

Comment: You'd think this would be easy to Google ...

Comment: That's what I and two friends thought too - over 1 year ago - still can't find anything.

Comment: Gotta be Asimov. He loved puns.

Comment: Could it have been a [Feghoot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feghoot)?

Comment: Could it be one of Spider Robinson's CALLAHAN'S CROSSTIME SALOON stories?

Comment: Definitely not one of Asimov's own stories.

Comment: I wish this had gotten answered!!

Answer (score 15):

This is [*Author, Author*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?42980) by Tim Colley, published in *Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine*, v. 5, no. 1, published 1981.

> Grabbing the lens, the Editor could just make out a tiny label
> with these words almost hidden by dribbled juice: Send to Sylph.
> "So what?”
> "I would deduce our friend here has been eavesdropping. Perhaps
> sound in his universe is less distinct than here, or his hearing may
> just be poor. Perhaps he’s heard you laying down the law to some
> aspiring author: certainly he knew that any unsolicited manuscript
> had to be accompanied by a stomped, Sylph-addressed canteloupe.”
> "How laborious.” The Editor groaned and turned the ice-pack to
> high.
> "But when you rejected his first submission, he must have thought
> he mis-heard you. So here he is again . . .”
> "With a stumpy, sulphur-tressed antelope,” completed the Kindly
> Editor, pounding softly on his desk.

You can find the full text at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Asimovs_v05n01_1981-01-19/Asimovs_v05n01_1981-01-19_djvu.txt)